# Chrome inactive tab not executing setInterval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I like listening music with a Chrome tab on Youtube while I'm working, but every hour the music stops and a message "Are you still there?" is displayed on it.
Yes, I'm still there, like everyday, 7 times a day :)

So I installed a Chrome extension called "Custom Stylesheet & Script" to run this simple JavaScript stuff:

```
setInterval(function(){
    let overlay = document.querySelector('iron-overlay-backdrop');
    if(overlay) overlay.click();
}, 1000);
```

This works great, but only if I am on the YouTube tab. If I'm working on another one the music eventually stops and I have to click on the YT tab for this JavaScript to run (so not really a win after all).

I found some posts mentioning that setInterval in inactive tabs have a low priority and will only trigger once or twice a second, in my case they don't trigger at all.

Thanks for any hint on what to look at :)

Comment: Maybe the site doesn't show `ytd-app` when backgrounded so your if branch doesn't run.

Comment: I actually added the ytd-app test afterwards so this code wouldn't be executed on every tab

Comment: If it takes an hour for YT to wonder if you are there then you don't need to set the `setInterval()` to work every second. Why not set it to 10 minutes, so change 1000 to 600000. The idea is that too many `setInterval()` calls in an inactive tab will eventually completely stop it, whereas a call every 10 minutes might not.

Comment: I suggest using MutationObserver instead of setInterval.

Comment: If I set the timer to 10 minutes, I would wait for 10 minutes before the code tells Youtube I'm here to continue de music :)

Comment: Oh, I see, it clicks on the message. I thought the Javascript would just do something to let Google think you were still there. You could try that. For instance by scrolling the page every 10 minutes...

Comment: I'll take a look at the MutationObserver and post here my results !

Answer (score 1):

After some tests, I found that the click on the "Ok" button to confirm was disabled by YouTube if the chrome tab isn't active, the setInterval was perfectly working after all.

If anyone is interested, I tried the MutationObserver method suggested by wOxxOm, and instead of clicking the confirmation button I just reload the page.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
if(-1 !== window.location.host.indexOf('youtube')) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

        let popupContainer = document.querySelector('ytd-popup-container');

        let observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {
            let confirmButton = popupContainer.querySelector('.yt-confirm-dialog-renderer paper-button');
            if(confirmButton){
                // confirmButton.click();
                document.location.reload(true);
            }
        });

        observer.observe(popupContainer, {childList: true});
    });
}
```